# Fish Shell Auditing

Tags: shell, fish

I would like to write a small script for the Fish Shell following this article - [How (and Why) to Log Your Entire Bash History](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/05/28/log-bash-history/).

Restrictions:

1. I didn't find any BASH `PROMPT_COMMAND` equivalent in Fish.
2. I am using a custom Oh My Fish prompt. It would be great if I didn't have to modify the custom fish prompt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're going about this the wrong way. You want to log all commands you enter? Fish already by default keeps the last 256k deduplicated entries from all sessions, so you don't actually need to do anything.

If you wanted a PROMPT_COMMAND equivalent, well, to display a prompt there's the `fish_prompt` function (which you have already customized), and to do something else every time a prompt appears there's the `fish_prompt` event, which you can define a listener for like

```
function name --on-event fish_prompt
    # do stuff
end
```

If you wish to log everything you execute to some other file, there's the `fish_preexec` event, so

```
function log_commands --on-event fish_preexec
    # fish_preexec functions receive the commandline as the argument (see `function --help`)
    echo $argv >> ~/fish.log
end
```

would work.

Comment: To expand on this, fish already records your entire history, and you can access it with `history`. fish also merges multiple sessions into a single history file, which is the main limitation of bash history.

Comment: Thank you for the responses - that was helpful. Note that the objective of logging all commands (including duplicates) is to have an audit of sorts as mentioned in the article and not to replace `fish_history`.